# How to use DataProtectionProvider?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm new to WinRT and was exploring it's security features and I've got a couple of questions regarding to Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider class:

- What encryption algorithm does it use (e.g. AES or TwoFish)?
- According to MSDN document you can use symmetric key for encryption, anyone knows what do you pass in as 'protectionDescription' constructor argument if you want to do this?
- Finally, the MSDN document says you have to use the parameter-less constructor before calling the UnprotectAsync method. How come you don't need to pass in a key to decrypt the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Good questions. Out of curiosity, have you tried the samples?

Comment: You mean the samples on MSDN? Yes I did read through it but it didn't answer any of my question and just create more question marks. For example, it's using 'LOCAL=user' as 'protectionDescription' parameter, which is not even one of the five possible entities in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I downloaded and went through the Metro samples as suggested by Ritch, I found out that I should be using classes under Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core namespace for data encryption.

Comment: Cool. They're a pretty good set. I've gotten quite a bit out of them.

Comment: May I know the reasoning behind this? I'm facing the same issue of choosing cryptography for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No one here explained or gave the answer to the original question. I couldn't find much information on DataProtectionProvider.