# DataProtectionProvider constructor protection description

Tags: c#, encryption

I am using the [DataProtectionProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) to encrypt the files in my applications local storage. But I'm having a hard time finding some solid examples/information about how to use the descriptor given in the constructor in the best way.

The descriptor examples given on msdn are:

> "SID=S-1-5-21-4392301 AND SID=S-1-5-21-3101812"
>
> "SDDL=O:S-1-5-5-0-290724G:SYD:(A;;CCDC;;;S-1-5-5-0-290724)(A;;DC;;;WD)"
>
> "LOCAL=user"
>
> "LOCAL=machine"
>
> "WEBCREDENTIALS=MyPasswordName"
>
> "WEBCREDENTIALS=MyPasswordName,myweb.com"

How secure are files encrypted with "LOCAL=user"? Can any application decrypt them as long as the same user is using the app?

How do I use "WEBCREDENTIALS=MyPasswordName"? Can I use a password from the password vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990320/how-to-use-dataprotectionprovider) suggest that you should use the [cryptography.core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx) assemblies instead, might be worth taking a look at

Comment: That's fair, but I can echo @Darajan 's question - I would like to understand how to interpret "LOCAL=user". I gather this is a very minimal example of an SDDL descriptor. Is the best way to understand the "scope" of this descriptor to go through the SDDL reference? Or is this a special case descriptor, outside of the syntax of an SDDL descriptor? Does this mean that all local users can decrypt this data? Or does it mean the local user that encrypted the data can decrypt it, and an admin or other local user could not decrypt it? I know I'm in danger of asking a ridiculously naive question.

Answer (score 0):

This question should also be tagged [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime).

I'm not sure how the "WEBCREDENTIALS=MyPasswordName" descriptor works but the "WEBCREDENTIALS=MyPasswordName,myweb.com" descriptor can (must?) refer to an entry made by your app in PasswordVault.

Entries in PasswordVault can be viewed in the "Control Panel ->  Credential Manager -> Web Credentials" pane.

Here is a method to encrypt and decrypt some data:

```cs
    // using System.Diagnostics;
    // using Windows.Storage.Streams;
    // using System.IO;
    // using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; // (convert streams from Windows. to System. and vice-versa)
    // using Windows.Security.Credentials;
    // using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
    // using Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection;
    public async void EnDeCryptDataUsingWebcredentials()
    {
        #region Set up environment

        // Specify variables for mock PasswordCredential
        string credentialResource = "MyResourceIdentifier";
        string credentialUserName = "Foo";
        string credentialPassword = "Bar";

        // Get a vault instance.
        PasswordVault passwordVault = new PasswordVault();

        // Inject new credential
        PasswordCredential testCredential = new PasswordCredential(credentialResource, credentialUserName, credentialPassword);
        passwordVault.Add(testCredential);

        #endregion Set up environment

        string dataToEncrypt = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("UnencryptedData: {0}", dataToEncrypt));

        // Assemble descriptor from PasswordCredential.
        PasswordCredential credential = passwordVault.Retrieve(credentialResource, credentialUserName);
        string dataProtectionDescriptor = String.Format("WEBCREDENTIALS={0},{1}", credential.UserName, credential.Resource);
        Debug.WriteLine("Encryption Descriptor: {0}", dataProtectionDescriptor);

        // Encrypt data.
        DataProtectionProvider encryptionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider(dataProtectionDescriptor);
        IBuffer unencryptedDataBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(dataToEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer inputDataBuffer = await encryptionProvider.ProtectAsync(unencryptedDataBuffer);

        // View encrypted data as string.
        string encryptedData = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputDataBuffer.AsStream()))
        {
            encryptedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("EncryptedData: {0}", encryptedData));

        // Decrypt data (never supply a descriptor for decryption).
        DataProtectionProvider decryptionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider();
        IBuffer outputDataBuffer = await decryptionProvider.UnprotectAsync(inputDataBuffer);

        // View decrypted data as string.
        string decryptedData = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputDataBuffer.AsStream()))
        {
            decryptedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("\nDecryptedData: {0}", decryptedData));
    }
```

Comment: using WEBCREDENTIALS descriptor turns out to generate sporadic exceptions (on some machines) of type:
System.Exception: Could not write data to disk. ---> System.Exception: Encryption failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090034)
So, proceed with caution.